# "Install" - Saxon

Tags: xml, xquery, saxon, xquery-sql

I am trying to "install" Saxon for xquery documents.

So I set the Classpath var with the saxon9he.jar as file name and tried in the cmd saxon9he but nothing happened. So I tried to execute a xquery file by:

```
java net.sf.saxon.Query
```

and i got:

```
C:\Users\Admin>java net.sf.saxon.Query
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/saxon/Query
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.saxon.Query
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: net.sf.saxon.Query.  Program will exit.
```

Whats wrong with my configuration?

**--UPDATE 1--**

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Studium\5tes Semster\Semistrukturierte Daten\3 Übung>jav
a -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query
No query file name
Saxon-HE 9.2.1.2J from Saxonica
Usage: java net.sf.saxon.Query [options] query {param=value}...
Options:
  -backup:on|off        Save updated documents before overwriting
  -config:filename      Use configuration file
  -cr:classname         Use specified CollectionURIResolver class
  -dtd:on|off           Validate using DTD
  -expand:on|off        Expand defaults defined in schema/DTD
  -explain[:filename]   Display compiled expression tree
  -ext:[on|off]         Allow|Disallow external Java functions
...
```

The classpath var seems to be set right...

Comment: Just to help your debugging try `java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query` Maybe there is some issue with your classpath variable.

Comment: is there probably an online xquery processor or a better program?

Comment: Have a look at [BaseX](http://www.basex.org) which provides a great GUI (and a CLI, of course, if you want it) with nice visualizations, great for learning XQuery.

Comment: thx!!! BaseX is perfect for xquery!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [saxon documentation shows](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xquery/commandline.xml) how to execute a XQuery from the command line:

> java  net.sf.saxon.Query   [options]   -q:queryfile   [ params...]

Additionally, [it states](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xquery/intro.xml):

> The XQuery processor may be invoked either from the operating system command line, or via an API from a user-written application. There is no graphical user interface provided.

And since it's java-based, it requires correct [handling of the classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29). So,if you don't have much experience with both java and using a cli application, another XQuery may be easier to handle. Besides BaseX, there's [Zorba](http://www.zorba-xquery.com); aquite complex solution would be [eXist-db](http://www.exist-db.org), a native XML database with XQuery processor and editor.